# How to set the width of an option in a select?

Tags: html

I have a html select with an option with a very long text. I wonder how to set the max-width of an option to a word wrap.

For exemple, I whant the option to wrap at 100px:

```
    <select style="width:100px">
    <option>
        skdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk nd
    </option>
    <option>
        skdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk nd
    </option>
    <option>
        skdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk nd
    </option>
    <option>
        skdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk nd
    </option>
    <option>
        skdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk nd
    </option>
    <option>
        skdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk ndskdfnsdjfn skdjfn sjkdn sdjkn sdjk nsdjkf nsdjkf nsdjkfn sjkf nsdjk nd
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152803/wrap-long-text-in-drop-down-list & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list

Comment: Sorry, I have not use those word in my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do word wrap with the standard option selects. You'll have to use a 3rd party tool or roll your own.