# How to wrap Text in DropDownList ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, word-wrap

I can't seems to find any solution on internet on wrapping the text in dropdownlist in ASP.net.
I don't want to do it server side, but do it with CSS or HTML.

Comment: I don't think its possible. A drop down list turns into a Html Option list. Jquery might be able to help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834231/how-to-wrap-text-in-html-option

Comment: Also: [Wrap long-text in drop-down list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1152803/55209) and [how to handle long text in dropdownlist control in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1116395/55209)

Comment: I Thank you ALL for your contributions. I will wrap the text with Jquery and going to apply alternate colors to items, so they are recognizable.